# Buttons in UIView are not having an effect when tapped

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I am using a view with buttons in it on my main view controller. I had the buttons working fine until recently when I began messing around with the constraints to make things appear better visually. After adjusting some sizes and constraints the buttons just stopped working.

Here is my setup: 
I have a custom view in which I setup 3 buttons and added constraints to them

```
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        let buttonSize: CGFloat = 90.0

        addSubview(photoButton)
        photoButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
        photoButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        addSubview(homeButton)
        homeButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: nil, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: photoButton.leadingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 20), size: .init(width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))

        addSubview(profileButton)
        profileButton.anchor(top: nil, leading: photoButton.trailingAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, trailing: nil, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: buttonSize, height: buttonSize))
    }
```

In my main view controller I added targets for the buttons, to call the functions when they are tapped.

```
let buttonView = HomeBottomControlsView()
```

in my view did load

```
        buttonView.homeButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openTrending), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonView.profileButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openProfile), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(overallStackView)
        view.addSubview(buttonView)

        overallStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        overallStackView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
        overallStackView.isLayoutMarginsRelativeArrangement = true
        overallStackView.layoutMargins = .init(top: 10, left: 12, bottom: 95, right: 12)

        buttonStackView.anchor(top: overallStackView.bottomAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor, padding: .init(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0), size: .init(width: 0, height: 0))
```

The buttons were working previously, until I began playing around with the auto layout constraints. Now I can not seem to get the buttons to be tappable anymore.

I was reading in other questions that buttons sometime d not work because of issues with initial frames. Is that the issues here?

Comment: Use the View Debugger to see if there's a constraints problem or an out-of-superview problem.

Comment: Your overallStackView is occupying the entire view. And you are setting the top constraint for buttonStackView to be the bottom anchor of overallStackView. That will never work.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla Thank you! I have set the buttonStackView Constraint first now and then based the bottom constraint of the overstackview to the top of the buttonStackView and it is working again!

Comment: I’ll write up an answer in case you want to accept it. Glad you got it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This view is already occupying the entire `view`

```
overallStackView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
```

and you are setting the topAnchor of the `buttonStackView` to be the bottom anchor of `overallStackView`. That is why the frames are not correctly positioned. You need to change the constraints of both `buttonStackView` and `overallStackView` so they do not overlap with each other